# Area between square and circumscribed circle is less than half the area of the circle.

Tags: geometry

Here's a figure I drew on desmos (ignore the circumscribed square):
[image]

My question: I want to be able to prove this without computing the area in terms of $\pi$

My method:
Let sidelength of $AB$ be $L$ and radius of circle be $r$

We can write $$r=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}L$$
Area between the square and circle = $S_1 = L^2(\frac{\pi}{2}-1)$
We need to show $$S_1 < L^2\frac{\pi}{4}$$
By solving the inequality we get $$\frac{\pi}{4} < 1 $$
This is numerically true, but it isn't a proof by geometry. Any ideas as to how I might start on a geometric proof?

Comment: this proof seems fine to me. Of course there are many ways you can try and show this. If you create $4$ rectangles at each side of the square with the other side being $\frac{a}{4}$, each circular segment is inside the rectangle on that side. Note that $\frac{a}{4} \geq \frac{a}{\sqrt2} - \frac{a}{2}$. Of course, you again have to know that $1.5 \gt \sqrt2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~djoyce/elements/bookXII/propXII2.html](https://mathcs.clarku.edu/%7Edjoyce/elements/bookXII/propXII2.html)

Found a proof in Euclid's Elements book XII, proposition 2

The diagrams for the quote below are on the link.

"Inscribe the square EFGH in the circle EFGH. Then the inscribed square is greater than the half of the circle EFGH, for if through the points E, F, G, and H we draw tangents to the circle, then the square EFGH is half the square circumscribed about the circle, and the circle is less than the circumscribed square, hence the inscribed square EFGH is greater than the half of the circle EFGH."

Answer (score 0):

Once you know the area of a circle is proportional to a square of its radius: $$S_C = \pi r^2$$ (whatever the value of $\pi$ actually is), then your conjecture is equivalent to $$\pi < 4$$ as you correctly shown.

This, however, follows directly from your drawing! The external square easily decomposes into four squares with edge $r$ each, hence its area is $4 r^2$ and this is greater than the area of a circle: $$S_C = \pi r^2 < 4 r^2$$